# Data/Time Formula Excel in VBA Program

Tags: vba, excel

I really have no idea if this is possible or not, but I'm trying to write an Excel program that uses the built-in date/time function to do a calculation and output it to a cell. It will use the downloaded date (located in column A), the last time of data entry (bottom row of B), and each independent data entry time (column B).

I want the formula in each cell to look like this:: 
A2 - Time(0,0,(B_Last - B_Current)/1000)

I'm assuming I will need it in some sort of loop.

My current code looks like this ::

```
Sub Bottom()

Dim Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Last As Double

Set myRange = Columns("B:B")

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
Set r1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)

For i = 1 To Count
Set r2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
r2 = r1 - Time(0, 0, (Last - r2) / 1000)

Next

End Sub
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA has much more "in-built power" than Excel and thus you don't really need to rely on Excel formulae when using VBA. But if you want to do it anyway, you have to do something like this:

```
Range("B" & i).Value = "=Time(0, 0, (" & Last - r2 & ") / 1000)"
```

To get the value from the cell:

```
Dim cellVal As Date
cellVal = Range("B" & i).Value
```

You just have to make sure that the VBA variables and the strings written to the cells are treated separatedly (with " and &, as shown above) and that you store the value of the given cell in a variable of the right type (if you rely on `string` type it would work with any content).

Some correction in your code:

```
Sub Bottom()

Dim Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Last As Double

Set myRange = Columns("B:B")

Last = 10 'What you want here??
Set r1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
Dim r1Val As Long
r1Val = r1.Value


Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)

For i = 1 To Count
    Set r2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
    r2.Value = "=" & r1Val & " - Time(0, 0," & CStr(Last) & "/ 1000)"  'r2 = r1 - Time(0, 0, (Last - r2) / 1000) -> r2 = ... Last - r2 does not make any sense; r2 is a whole date and Last - r2 refers to a part of a date
Next

End Sub
```

This is just a simple version of your code showing you some of things you shouldn't be doing: you are mixing up ranges with values, not considering different types, accounting for variables which I cannot even understand, etc.

Just take this code, analyse it carefully, understand what you have done wrong and keep adding functionalities step by step, by doing some research every time. The ideas are very simple:

- You can set as many cells as you wish as a range.
- A range can have different contents (got through range.Value); these contents are associated to a variable in VBA which has to have
  the same type (string works for any content).
- When you write to a cell, you write the whole text (if you put "=" ahead, Excel understand it as a formula).
- When you read from a cell, you get the final value (the one from the formula, if applicable).

Etc.

I recommend you to do some research and get much more used to VBA than what you are right now.

Comment: Thank you!! I keep getting a compile error: object required when I run the new program; do you have any suggestions?  I don't need to use Excel formula, that was just the only way I knew how to do a calculation with the date/time. Is there a better way to do this through VBA?

Comment: You code has quite a few errors. Let me update my answer with a short/corrected version which you can run and from which you can learn to write a proper code.

Comment: Take a look at the updated code and work (quite a lot) by your own because your ideas do not seem to be too clear yet.

Comment: Regarding your question of there is a better way to do that with VBA; VBA has its own date functions and its own date type (which delivers something equivalent to what you are doing with the Time function). I recommend you to do some research regarding what VBA can/cannot before trying it with Excel. For example, if you want to compare dates, analyse the in-built time/date functionalities of VBA.